# Explaining lack of mixed dancing

Tags: heterodox, mechitza-partition, dance

How do you explain to non-frum relatives why your simcha will have separate dancing?

Comment: This sounds like 2 questions, with the first being covered by http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18135/759 (and see linked questions to there). I recommend editing out the first question and sticking with the second.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the title doesn't match the body of the question.

Comment: Related to the second part: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18469/5

Comment: And dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9480/5