# Mixed dancing events

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, women, shulchan-aruch, parties-celebrations

I know that HaShem hates mixed dancing parties and events, but I , like everybody, do need sources to back this up, so can you guys please provide sources, like maybe in the talmud and shulchan aruch that prohibits mixed dancing? I remember there was a story that after the amalekites were defeated, Moshe Rabbeinu and Miriam both made separate parties, one for males, and one for females. Where was this story to be found? thanks

Comment: possible dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18135/759

Answer (score 3):

The Chofetz Chaim wrote many seforim which are well less known to the masses,and one of them is called [Geder Olam](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/36306). In this sefer the Chofetz Chaim goes through many laws of modesty,however in chapter 9 ([Chasimas HaSefer pg 38 in hyperlinked version](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36306&st=&pgnum=38)) he dedicates the whole chapter to this exact issue. The Chofetz Chaim brings numerous sources from the Bible,Talmud,and Rishonim that cite prohibitions which correlate with the prohibition of mixed dancing and mingling.  The Chofetz Chaim also stresses the importance to rebuke those who stumble on this prohibition.

However, see Bnei Banim chelek 1 siman 37(http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20021&st=&pgnum=119) which discusses mixed dancing in a circle fashion which may be a different story. In fact Rav Henkin notes the Kol Bo(see number 9 of the tshuvah) who made a decree to forbid mixed dancing and Rav Henkin holds this decree still applies today. So even if you come out from the sugya that in some cases its technically permitted,still the ban of the Kol Bo is in effect.

note: please look up the Geder Olam for (the exact sources,it would be too much to write all the sources now while I am typing on the phone.)

Comment: Note that the question seemed to be about mixed events, not dancing in particular.

Comment: he discusses mingling as well

Comment: @sam then perhaps mention it in your answer, as it stands now, ikkar hasser min hasefer.