# Government-forced mixed swimming

Tags: tznius-modesty, politics-government, dina-dmalchusa-dina, chilul-kidush-hashem, swimming

[Mixed swimming](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/mixed-swimming-in-a-pool) is prohibited even for [older children](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29473/mixed-swimming-and-a-10-year-old-boy). How should we react if [the government would try to force](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/10/world/europe/swiss-muslim-girls-must-attend-swim-classes-with-boys-court-says.html) such upon us? Would we e.g. have to let ourselves be killed rather than obey?

---

<sup>**Note:** Luckily, I have settled in a place where such a problem is extremely unlikely, so this question is purely theoretical.</sup>

Comment: Note that the evidence you present for your question in the first link is an anonymous internet character quoting no sources. Hardly compelling.

Comment: Your source for it being prohibited for older children, is another anonymous internet character, telling us his impression is that it depends on the community... Hardly a compelling source to base a question on.

Comment: Note that you seem to be assuming that there is a universal prohibition for men and women to swim in the same vicinity. If, however,  (and this seems to be the case) it is simply the subset of a separate prohibition, then the determinant would no loner be the swimming, but that other factor, and without knowing whether that factor is present, the question becomes impossible to answer.

Comment: Note that it is not clear to me that the case in question applied to private schools. Before mass suicide / death by tyrannical liberal government, application to private schools should probably be considered.

Comment: What is the difference between mixed swimming and mixed walking?

Comment: @mevaqesh ...as should Aliyah.

Comment: @DoubleAA No, that's definitely yehareg ve'al ya'avor.

Comment: @DoubleAA for fishes mixed walking is more threatening,  for humans mixed swimming  is more threatening

Comment: Are you talking about a time when Jews are being systematically oppressed? Because I think that's the only situation when we'd have to make a kiddush Hashem for tznius. And then, yes, we would