# Men and women swimming together

Tags: halacha, women, men-male, swimming

Is there any issue with men and women swimming togther in the same swimming pool if all people are covered properly with coverups and married womens hair is covered etc? If its not allowed what are the issues

Comment: There is no special issur of being in water with the opposite gender when they are dressed appropriately.  However ,there may be an issue of kalos rosh

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/mixed-swimming-in-a-pool